# a:hover background image swap not working in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

a.dismiss-cross {
        background: transparent url(/images/cross-grey.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
        float: right;
        border: none;
        width: 19px;
        height: 19px;
        display: block;
    }

```
a.dismiss-cross:hover {
    background-position: 0 -19px;
}
```

And implemented with

```
 <a class='dismiss-cross' href='#'></a>
```

Lo and behold it doesn't work in IE whereas its fine in every other browser.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: not working in any version of IE? Or just IE6?

Comment: Did you try using a &nbsp; within the a element like so <a ...>&nbsp;</a>?

Comment: The code you posted does work with IE6. Unless there is something wonky with your image, there must be something else affecting it. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure, but as far as I remember you have to **explicitely** declare the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes:

```
a.dismiss-cross:link,
a.dismiss-cross:visited {
    background: transparent url(/images/cross-grey.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    display: block;
}
```

And, by the way, if you use floating, there's no reason on assigning a block display. Floating implies block display. But... IE6 has a bug with floated elements that have margins. It doubles the margins. The fix is quite simple though. You set `display: inline;`. This is ignored by all the other browsers, but fixes IE6.